# Are these two spaces $(\mathbb{R},T_\text{up})$ and $(\mathbb{R},T_\text{low})$ homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

This is a topology question, the more formal question is this:

> Are the spaces ($\mathbb{R},T_\text{up}$)and ($\mathbb{R},T_\text{low}$) homeomorphic?

Here, $T_\text{up}$ is the upper topology consisting of the sets $\{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}\cup\{(a, \infty) \mid a \in \mathbb{R}\}$, and $T_\text{low} := \{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\} \cup \{(−\infty, a) \mid a \in \mathbb{R}\}$ defines the lower topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

I know these two are homeomorphic if there exists a homeomorphism between them, which is a function $f: (\mathbb{R},T_\text{up}) \to (\mathbb{R},T_\text{low})$ which is bijective, continuous, and has a continuous inverse. However, I'm clueless about how to find such a function or how to prove that they are not homeomorphic.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try $f(x) = -x$.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you, could you give hints on how to prove the function is continuous?

Comment: @Liz Compute what the preimageof $(a, \infty)$ is. What condition on these is required for $f$ to be continuous?

Comment: @AreaMan is it (-∞,a)?

Comment: @Liz $(-\infty, \color{red}{-}a)$.  By the way, for appropriate mathematics formatting, use `$(-\infty,-a)$`.  In general, you can right-click on math on MSE, and choose the option "Show TeX" to see how it was written.

Comment: @XanderHenderson thank you pointing this out, will keep in mind!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the intuition here is that a negative ray $(-\infty, a)$ and a positive ray $(b,\infty)$ are basically the same thing.  Thus the intuitive candidate for a homeomorphism is the map
$$ f : (\mathbb{R},T_{\text{up}}) \to (\mathbb{R},T_\text{low}) : x \mapsto -x. $$
I think that it is fairly easy to see that this is a bijection, though here is the proof for completeness:

- *Injectivity:*  Suppose that $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = f(y)$.  By definition of $f$, this implies that $-x = -y$, which is possible only if $x= y$.  Therefore $f$ is injective.
- *Surjective:*  Suppose that $x \in (\mathbb{R},T_\text{low})$.  Then $-x \in (\mathbb{R},T_\text{up})$ and $f(-x) = -(-x) = x$.  Therefore $f$ is surjective.
- *Continuity of $f$:* Continuity is slightly more subtle.  We want to show that if $V \subseteq \mathbb{R},T_\text{low})$ is open, then $f^{-1}(V) \subseteq (\mathbb{R}, T_\text{up})$ is also open.  First, let's deal with the easy cases:  if $V= \mathbb{R}$ then $f^{-1}(V) = \mathbb{R}$ (this follows immediately from the bijectivity of $f$), and if $V = \emptyset$ then $f^{-1}(V) = \emptyset$ (this follows from basic theory—there is essentially nothing to show here).  Of significance here is the fact that $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are (necessarily) open in both topologies.  Now suppose that $V = (-\infty, a)$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is an arbitrary open set with respect to the lower topology.  It is not too hard to see that
  $$f^{-1}(V)
  = f^{-1}((-\infty,a))
  = (-a,\infty),$$
  which is an open set in the upper topology.  Thus if a set $V$ is open with respect to the lower topology, then the preimage of $V$ under $f$ is also open.  Therefore $f$ is continuous.
- *Continuity of $f^{-1}$:* Finally, we need to show that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.  But note that $f^{-1}(x) = -x$, so we can apply the same argument as above.

This finishes the proof, therefore $\mathbb{R}$ with the upper topology is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ with the lower topology, with the homeomorphism given by $x \mapsto -x$.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! it's really helpful :)